# Confusion between objects and functions - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in JavaScript and I want to understand something, for example in jQuery we have the jQuery object (often called $), but I'm confused here:

In jQuery when we want to select DOM nodes, we use jQuery selector, for example like this:

```
$('div');
```

But when we want to make a post to a server we call it like:

```
$.post({...});
```

My question is, how an object can behave like a function and an object at the same time? When I use `$('div')`, I'm calling a function and when I'm using `$.post({...})` I'm accessing a function inside an object.

Comment: I suggest you to please review http://jquery.com/ it will help you a lot for more and enough learning

Comment: all simple: `$` - not an object, this a function.

Comment: @Grundy no `$` is an object *and* a function

Comment: @freedomn-m, `$` is a `function`. this enough :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary:  functions *are* objects.

```
function foo() {
    alert("bar");
}

foo.bar = "foobar";

alert(foo.bar);
foo();
alert(foo);
```

They're just special objects that you can add `()` to to call / run.

Answer (score 3):

---

```
$( "h1" ).remove();
```

Most jQuery methods are called on jQuery objects as shown above; these methods are said to be part of the `$.fn` namespace, or the *"jQuery prototype,"* and are best thought of as jQuery object methods.

However, there are several methods that do not act on a selection; these methods are said to be part of the *jQuery namespace,* and are best thought of as core jQuery methods.

**This distinction can be incredibly confusing to new jQuery users. Here's what you need to remember:**

***1)*** Methods called on jQuery selections are in the `$.fn` namespace, and automatically receive and return the selection as this.

***2)*** Methods in the `$` namespace are generally utility-type methods, and do not work with selections; they are not automatically passed any arguments, and their return value will vary.

Comment: I'm fine too, thank you for describing some JQuery internals for me :), can you show me how i can get this behavior in javascript, so how i can get a function/object in the same reference :)

Comment: @AbdessamedMansouri, just create function, and add property

Comment: @AbdessamedMansouri see my answer for how to do that